# Changing image using radio button and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I've been trying out a few things and this appears to not working quite the way I wish it to.

```
<div id="box1">
    <h2>Question 1</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q1a" name="q1"><label for="q1a">A</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q1b" name="q1"><label for="q1b">B</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q1c" name="q1"><label for="q1c">C</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q1d" name="q1"><label for="q1d">D</label></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="../images/q1.jpg" alt="" class="src">
</div>
<div id="box2">
    <h2>Question 2</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q2a" name="q2"><label for="q2a">A</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q2b" name="q2"><label for="q2b">B</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q2c" name="q2"><label for="q2c">C</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q2d" name="q2"><label for="q2d">D</label></li>
    </ul>
            <img src="../images/q2.jpg" alt="" class="src">
</div>
<div id="box3">
    <h2>Question 3</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q3a" name="q3"><label for="q3a">A</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q3b" name="q3"><label for="q3b">B</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q3c" name="q3"><label for="q3c">C</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="q3d" name="q3"><label for="q3d">D</label></li>
    </ul>
            <img src="../images/q3.jpg" alt="" class="src">
</div>
```

I have 3 boxes, each with a unique id. 4 questions each, each radio button labeled correctly. My script for changing it along these lines.

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    $(this).next('img').attr('src','../images/'+$(this).attr('id')+'.jpg');
});
```

I understand that if I replaced the first $(this) with $('img') that it would work, but it would end up changing all the images, and I only want the radio to reflect in the image in the same parent div. Any help pointing me towards the right direction would be much appreciated.

I suspect that when I query for the img, the this i'm using for the images doesn't work the way I want it to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next` only selects the next sibling the element, you can use `closest` method and select the target image using `find` method.

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    $(this)
         .closest('div')
         .find('img')
         .prop('src','../images/'+this.id+'.jpg');
});
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of using the other statement by Explosion Pills? Would it be faster to select the div or by ul?

Comment: Why are you using `.prop` for `src` instead of `.attr`?

Comment: @stepquick Well, both select the same element, if you add another element after `ul` in your markup the above statement won't work.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I prefer to use `prop` for modifying _properties_ of elements.

Comment: @undefined thanks for the clarification. I didn't plan on adding anything beyond how it's structured now.

Comment: I will be going with your answer, though @ExplosionPills definitely works well. Your's appears to actually make more sense.

Comment: @undefined I'd just like to point out that the "if you add another element after `ul`" while true, is incomplete.  If you change the container from `div` to some other element yours will not work either.  If he does plan to modify the html frequently, it may be wise to use a class as the known container or sibling

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, you are right, thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

The img is the "next" sibling of the ancestor `<ul>` of the radio button (apparently).  You can traverse the DOM pretty easily with jQuery:

```
$(this).closest('ul').next('img')...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').find('img').attr('src','../images/'+$(this).attr('id')+'.jpg');
});
```

[.closest()](http://jqapi.com/#p=closest)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').find('img')
    .attr('src','../images/'+$(this).attr('id')+'.jpg');
});
```

Here is the docs http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

There is one change you need to make.

```
$(this).parent().parent().next('img').attr('src','../images/'+$(this).attr('id')+'.jpg');
```

what `.parent().parent()` will do is get parent container of radio and the get `img` tag.